# Download files from Document Library through Java

Tags: document-library, download

How can I download files from SharePoint using Java?

I need to download all files under a folder using JavaAPI

Comment: What version of sherepoint?
Maybe this project helpful java-sharepoint-library. https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean JavaScript, not the other (older) programming language [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)).

You can not download files with JavaScript as it runs in the Browser
and **can not write to you local FileSystem**

Note: you can [generate a file with JavaScript and **ask the user to save the file**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side?hl=en)

For accesing SharePoint and extracting content you can use [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), or .[Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

- [Download a File from SharePoint using PowerShell](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2014/02/download-file-from-sharepoint-using.html)
- [Download all File Versions from SharePoint](http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Download-Versions.htm)

and yes.. you can do it with Java as well (if you really want)
(*that other programming language which is NOT JavaScript*)

Purists will say you can do it with JavaScript as [NodeJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) *uses* JavaScript

You could also open the Library (from IE browser only) with '[Open in Explorer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yM974e6CMY)' and copy the contents by hand

then you could [map that folder as a Network Mapping](http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Map_Document_Libraries_as_Network_Shares)
and use good old (*way older than Java*) .batch file scripting

Comment: Java is older than JavaScript? They where both released in 1995 so it must be a close call ;)

Comment: No, Java is from '90 or '91 .. or I was in a programming Matrix/Star Trek timewarp trap  ☕  .. I worked for the uni so it may not have been publically available yet

Comment: Probably, Wikipedia states 95 for both languages :)

Answer (score 0):

Some useful examples you can find here
http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/tutorial/index.html

JShare is SharePoint API for Java and Andoid

Comment: I tried JShare but it not running.My SharePoint version is 10.